# k8s statefullset match availability zones with nodeselector

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

How do I use the id/number from kubernetes statefullset to match node selector to availability zone ?

e.g. pod-0  should have nodeSelector zone-1
and pod-1 zone-2
and pod-2 zone-3

```
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: topology.kubernetes.io/zone
            operator: In
            values:
            - zone{{ id + 1 }}
```

Comment: You can't do that, but you *can* specify a [Pod anti-affinity rule](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity) that will ensure your pods are each scheduled in a distinct zone.

Comment: Go Through this [blog](https://medium.com/kubernetes-tutorials/learn-how-to-assign-pods-to-nodes-in-kubernetes-using-nodeselector-and-affinity-features-e62c437f3cf8) might help you in How to Assign Pods to Nodes in Kubernetes Using nodeSelector and Affinity Features and also you can use [Pod Topology Spread Constraints](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/topology-spread-constraints/#node-labels) in assigning zones.